# Override local dependency management

Tags: maven, dependency-management

Apologies this is a little basic and vague for stackoverflow so I'll hover over the delete button.  I've used java & maven for a while but not had this issue before.  Essentially I thought I'd spend some time between projects looking at an open source project (randomly chose PMD) and I'm struggling to build the project (well even to do a mvn clean!)

I think this is because there is some company level dependency management forcing the dependency searches to happen in a local repository and not proceed to Maven Central.  So I get this error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pmd-test: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-test:jar:6.10.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   net.sourceforge.pmd:pmd-core:jar:6.10.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://[Local-server]/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the
>   local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

This is new to me and I'm not sure how it would be done and so I'm not sure how to search for other ways to circumvent it.  I'm not really looking to do anything hacky, if it is a setting which does not have a reasonable work around I'll just live with it or discuss it internally but could anyone tell me what terminology I should look for to find out more about it (or do I have to read all documentation around dependency management?!)

Comment: Are you sure this is not a multi-module project and you tried to build just a part of it?

Comment: no sorry went for a run and remembered that I'd made a lot of changes to settings.xml for a previous project.  Deleted those project specific changes and all works well...

Answer (score 0):

This issue was in settings.xml.  These were set up with a specific active profile set to the local repository.  I'll leave this here as a warning to others unless anyone wants me to delete it.